# Docker Swarm and autoredeploy when Docker image updated

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, swarm

We use Docker Swarm and Docker Compose for deploy services.
We developing some services and dockerizing they into images and I want autoredeploy service when our docker image updated.

How do you do autoredeploy on this technology stack or on other stack?